# Validation of data dump created from postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, etl, data-migration, pg-dump

There is a postgres SQL database with 5 tables and when a dump is created out of it how could we validate that dump is comprising of all the data of the table . Could there any chance of file stream issue and only half file could be created.
As this is required for data migration from one system I want to have a checkpoint if the database dump is valid with all data.

Comment: If there is a problem when you run `pg_dump` you would get an error from the command. If you don't trust the tool then I'm not sure what else you could do other than restore the database and check approximate table row-counts.

Comment: Also it is important to realize that `pg_dump` takes a snapshot of a moving target, so the data that you see in the output may not reflect what you see in the source database.